# MATLAB ambigfun not working

Tags: matlab

I'm getting an error when I try to use MATLAB's `ambigfun`.  The error message is:

"The pulse is longer than the available data in X."

There is no "X" that I'm passing to the function, so I can't figure out what is causing the problem.  I'm passing it a complex signal vector 's' that is relatively short (100 samples).

```
afmag = ambgfun(s,fs, 1/T);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should ask this in a Matlab forum, since it isn't a signal processing question.

Comment: I suggest reading the help file. https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/ambgfun.html . "X" is the first argument